# Run a Google Cloud Function at specific time only once

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have job(script) which is written in nodejs.

I have another API which writes data (`Id and time-t1`) to the Cloud Spanner. As soon as the API is a hit I want to run the same job at given `time-t1` and pass `id` as parameter

Can I write some code in my API which will trigger the job at a given time (Note - for a single hit on API job should run job only once). I tried searching on the net but could only find periodic scheduler.

Comment: Have you considered leveraging Cloud Tasks ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/ ... this capability offers one the ability to forward schedule work to be performed at a subequent date/time.

Comment: @Kolban I want to run the cloud task at specific time `T1`. Then I would like to run the same task again at specific time `T2`. Time `T1` and `T2` are not known beforehand. They are user-configurable. I don't think cloud task provides this functionality.

Comment: From the original question, I had understood you wanted to run a script once at a time in the future.  Cloud Tasks can do that.  However if you want to run it twice at two different times, then you would likely need to register two tasks; one to run at T1 and another to run at T2.

Comment: How to register the task to run at time `T1`? Note: The time `T1` is configurable through API,  not known beforehand.

Comment: When we create a Task, we can optionally supply a "scheduleTime" ... see https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task   There are APIs for working with Cloud Tasks so one doesn't have to code REST.  Probably a good idea to have a read at all the Cloud Task docs.

Comment: The cloud task are an option, also you can take a look to Cloud Scheduler [1] that allows you to schedule virtually any job, including batch, big data jobs, cloud infrastructure operations,etc.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/

Comment: @AndieVega Cloud Scheduler allows to schedule the cron job and we need to know the time beforehand. In my case, I will have multiple requests from API which will give me time `T` and I have to run the script at a given time `T` for each request.

Example:
API gets hit for the first time. Input id='123', time = 5pm. Expected output: Run a job at 5 pm with parameter '123'
API gets hit for the second time. Input id='90', time = 3am. Expected output: Run a job at 3 am with parameter '90'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to schedule a task for a specific dynamic time you can use Google Cloud Task and Google Cloud Functions
Read it here:
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf