# Google cloud scheduler for google cloud run using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to write a nodejs script which calls google cloud scheduler to schedule a cloud run service to be run only once (non recurring event). How can I do it?

I've checked out this library npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/scheduler , but couldn't find a way to create a non recurring job.

I've tried something like this

```
const { CloudSchedulerClient } = require('@google-cloud/scheduler');
const axios = require('axios');


const projectId = 'project-id';
const location = 'location'; 
const jobName = 'job-name';
const cloudRunURL = 'cloud-run-url';

async function createJob() {
  const client = new CloudSchedulerClient();

  const parent = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`;
  const job = {
    name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/jobs/${jobName}`,
    httpTarget: {
      uri: cloudRunURL,
      httpMethod: 'GET',
    },
    schedule: '0 12 * * *',
    timeZone: 'UTC', 
  };

  try {
    const [createdJob] = await client.createJob({
      parent: parent,
      job: job,
    });

    console.log('Job created:', createdJob.name);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating job:', err);
  }
}


createJob();
```

But I'm stuck How to make it non recurring?

Comment: It's not clear whether you've tried anything yet. Did you read through https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/scheduler which is the Node client library for Google Cloud Scheduler?

Comment: Actually I tried using this library, but I'm unable to figure out, how to form non recurrring events.

Comment: So that should be in the question - show what you've tried, and describe how it doesn't do what you want. That would make a *much* better question than effectively "just give me the code".

Comment: (It's not immediately clear to me that Cloud Scheduler can be used to create non-recurring jobs at all, mind you - that's not a matter of code, that's a matter of general product capability. I'd suggest reading through the Cloud Scheduler docs in detail for that.)

Comment: Okay, can you please suggest me any cloud based service which have the capabilites of scheduling the cloud run service to execute just once. I've checked out cloud run and cloud task, but it didn't help.

Comment: Cloud task will work for this use case, where I want to trigger a task for future only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet, stated [**Cloud Scheduler**](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) is designed for recurring jobs. Thus, creating a job to run only once is not intended.

[**Cloud Tasks**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) should be able to satisfy your use case. Tasks are meant for one time execution and can be scheduled up to 30 days in the future. Each task has its own payload and can call any public HTTP endpoint using this [**beta feature**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks).

Also have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task) where there are API’s for working with Cloud Tasks so one doesn't have to code REST. Probably a good idea to have a read at all the Cloud Task docs.

Also have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57113677/18265702) for reference.

If you are not satisfied with the above options feel free to raise a new [Feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/home) explaining your use case and requesting non recurring functionality in cloud scheduler. You can refer [issue tracker page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) when raising a feature request.